# Configuring ViteJS for Web App Deployment with Updated Directory Structure: Error on Vercel Deployment

Tags: javascript, deployment, vite, vercel, production

I'm working on a web development project using ViteJS, HTML, Tailwind CSS, and JavaScript. I've decided to update the project directory structure and I'm having trouble configuring Vite and deploying the app with the new structure.

After moving the package.json file to the "frontend" directory, Vite and all associated package scripts have been relocated. I can build and preview the project locally by navigating to the "frontend" directory and running "npm run build". However, when I push the changes to GitHub and try to redeploy on Vercel, I get an error.

I'm unsure whether Vite, build scripts, and backend dependencies should be installed at the root of the project or if there's a step I'm missing.

##### The original structure:

```
├── node_modules
    └── ...
├── public
    └── ...
├── src
    ├── common
        └── ...
    ├── components
        └── ...
    ├── hoc
        └── ...
    ├── styles
        └── ...
    ├── utils
        └── ...
    ├── App.jsx
    ├── index.css
    ├── main.jsx
    └── styles.js
├── .env
├── .gitignore
├── index.html
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── post.css.config.cjs
├── README.md
├── tailwin.config.cjs
└── vite.config.js
```

##### The new structure:

```
├── backend
    └──server.js
├── frontend
    ├── node_modules
        └── ...
    ├── public
        └── ...
    ├── src
        ├── common
            └── ...
        ├── components
            └── ...
        ├── hoc
            └── ...
        ├── styles
            └── ...
        ├── utils
            └── ...
        ├── App.jsx
        ├── index.css
        ├── main.jsx
        └── styles.js
    ├── .gitignore
    ├── index.html
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── package.json <--- Vite build scripts live here
    ├── post.css.config.cjs
    ├── README.md
    ├── tailwin.config.cjs
    └── vite.config.js
├── node_modules
  └── ...
├── .env
├── .gitignore
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── README.md
```

*Frontend Scripts*

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "host": "vite --host",
    "preview": "vite preview --port 8080",
    "build-css": "node-sass src/styles/custom.scss src/styles/custom.css"
  },
```

To elaborate, I have moved the package.json file to the "frontend" directory, which has relocated Vite and all associated package scripts. I can build and preview the project locally by navigating to the "frontend" directory and running "npm run build". However, upon pushing the changes to GitHub and attempting a redeploy on Vercel, I encounter an error.

##### Vercel Error

```
sh: vite: command not found
Error: Command "vite build" exited with 127
BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_127: Command "vite build" exited with 127
```

##### vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import dns from 'dns'

dns.setDefaultResultOrder('verbatim')
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd());

  return {
    plugins: [react()],
    server: {
      port: 3000
    },
    define: {
      'process.env': env,
    },
    build: {
      outDir: './dist',
      emptyOutDir: true
    }
  };
});
```

I'm uncertain whether I should have Vite, build scripts, and backend dependencies installed at the root of the project or if there's a specific step I'm missing with the configuration process. I apologize for the novice question, but I'm seeking guidance to resolve this issue and advance my development skills.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After hours of staring at my code and scratching my head, I realized the answer was right under my nose - or rather, in the Vercel settings. The *solution* to my directory restructuring woes was as simple as updating the ***"Root Directory***" field under **General Settings**.

For those who, like me, were lost in the sea of subdirectories, this field *specifies the location* of your code within your project. In my case, I needed to set it to the root directory of my project, which was conveniently located in the `frontend` relative path.

So don't be like me, folks. Remember to *always* check your settings **before** you start tearing your hair out over code that isn't even the problem.